# Strange results in parallel analysis -- weird output by rstudio but not R-Fiddle

Tags: factor-analysis, parallel-analysis

**Major UPDATE based on discussion with Aleksandr Blekh's answer (thanks so much!):**

This MRE would run with no problem in R-Fiddle

```
library(psych)

data(bock)

fa.parallel.poly(lsat6)
```

**Output from R-Fiddle (Graph omitted as not relevant with error), no difference in no of factors suggested by the first and second line**

```
 See the graphic output for a description of the results
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  3  and the number of components =  1 
Call: fa.parallel.poly(x = lsat6)
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  3  and the number of components =  1 

 Eigen Values of 
  Original factors Simulated data Original components simulated data
1             0.79           0.76                1.62           1.22
2             0.14           0.13                1.00           1.10
3             0.04           0.03                0.88           1.00
```

**Output from R-Studio (Graph omitted as not relevant with error), note there are difference in no of factors suggested by the first (3) and second line (0), and the eigen Values section looks like messed up**

```
 See the graphic output for a description of the results
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  3  and the number of components =  1 
Call: fa.parallel.poly(x = lsat6)
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  0  and the number of components =  1 

 Eigen Values of 
  Original factors Simulated data Original components simulated data   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
1             0.79              1                  10           0.58 0.39 0.39 0.57 0.29 0.19 1.06 0.87 0.26 -2.02
    NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
1 0.12 1.62  1 10 1.17 0.04 1.15 1.16 0.03 1.11 1.24 0.14 0.58 -1.03 0.01
```

Here is the fresh results from R-studio together with sessionInfo() and options():

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library(psych)
> 
> data(bock)
> 
> fa.parallel.poly(lsat6)


  fa.parallel.poly |....................................................................................................| 100%

 See the graphic output for a description of the results
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  3  and the number of components =  1 
Call: fa.parallel.poly(x = lsat6)
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  0  and the number of components =  1 

 Eigen Values of 
  Original factors Simulated data Original components simulated data   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
1             0.79              1                  10           0.58 0.39 0.39 0.57 0.29 0.19 1.06 0.87 0.26 -2.02
    NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA
1 0.12 1.62  1 10 1.17 0.04 1.15 1.16 0.03 1.11 1.24 0.14 0.58 -1.03 0.01
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] psych_1.5.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] mnormt_1.5-1   parallel_3.0.2 tools_3.0.2   
> options()
$add.smooth
[1] TRUE

$bitmapType
[1] "quartz"

$browser
function (url) 
{
    .Call("rs_browseURL", url)
}
<environment: 0x7fd21312cdc8>

$browserNLdisabled
[1] FALSE

$buildtools.check
    function (action) 
    {
        if (identical(.Platform$pkgType, "mac.binary.mavericks")) {
        .Call("rs_canBuildCpp")
    }
    else {
        if (!.Call("rs_canBuildCpp")) {
            .rs.installBuildTools(action)
            FALSE
        }
        else {
            TRUE
        }
    }
}
<environment: 0x7fd2131ecbc8>

$buildtools.with
function (code) 
{
    .rs.addRToolsToPath()
    on.exit(.rs.restorePreviousPath(), add = TRUE)
    force(code)
}
<environment: 0x7fd2131ecbc8>

$CBoundsCheck
[1] FALSE

$check.bounds
[1] FALSE

$citation.bibtex.max
[1] 1

$continue
[1] "+ "

$contrasts
        unordered           ordered 
"contr.treatment"      "contr.poly" 

$defaultPackages
[1] "datasets"  "utils"     "grDevices" "graphics"  "stats"     "methods"  

$demo.ask
[1] "default"

$deparse.cutoff
[1] 60

$device
[1] "RStudioGD"

$device.ask.default
[1] FALSE

$digits
[1] 7

$dvipscmd
[1] "dvips"

$echo
[1] TRUE

$editor
[1] "vi"

$encoding
[1] "native.enc"

$error
(function () 
{
    .rs.breakOnError(TRUE)
})()

$example.ask
[1] "default"

$expressions
[1] 5000

$ggvis.renderer
[1] "svg"

$help_type
[1] "html"

$help.search.types
[1] "vignette" "demo"     "help"    

$help.try.all.packages
[1] FALSE

$HTTPUserAgent
[1] "R (3.0.2 x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 x86_64 darwin10.8.0)"

$internet.info
[1] 2

$keep.source
[1] TRUE

$keep.source.pkgs
[1] FALSE

$locatorBell
[1] TRUE

$mailer
[1] "mailto"

$max.print
[1] 10000

$menu.graphics
[1] FALSE

$na.action
[1] "na.omit"

$nwarnings
[1] 50

$OutDec
[1] "."

$pager
function (files, header, title, delete.file) 
{
    for (i in 1:length(files)) {
        if ((i > length(header)) || !nzchar(header[[i]])) 
            fileTitle <- title
        else fileTitle <- header[[i]]
        .Call("rs_showFile", fileTitle, files[[i]], delete.file)
    }
}
<environment: 0x7fd2131ecbc8>

$papersize
[1] "a4"

$pdfviewer
[1] "/usr/bin/open"

$pkgType
[1] "mac.binary"

$printcmd
[1] "lpr"

$prompt
[1] "> "

$repos
                     CRAN 
"http://cran.rstudio.com" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE

$restart
function (afterRestartCommand = "") 
{
    afterRestartCommand <- paste(as.character(afterRestartCommand), 
        collapse = "\n")
    .Call("rs_restartR", afterRestartCommand)
}
<environment: 0x7fd2131ecbc8>

$rl_word_breaks
[1] " \t\n\"\\'`><=%;,|&{()}"

$scipen
[1] 0

$show.coef.Pvalues
[1] TRUE

$show.error.messages
[1] TRUE

$show.signif.stars
[1] TRUE

$str
    $str$strict.width
[1] "no"

$str$digits.d
[1] 3

$str$vec.len
[1] 4


$str.dendrogram.last
[1] "`"

$stringsAsFactors
[1] TRUE

$texi2dvi
[1] "/usr/bin/texi2dvi"

$timeout
[1] 60

$ts.eps
[1] 1e-05

$ts.S.compat
[1] FALSE

$unzip
[1] "/usr/bin/unzip"

$useFancyQuotes
[1] TRUE

$verbose
[1] FALSE

$viewer
function (url, height = NULL) 
{
    if (!is.character(url) || (length(url) != 1)) 
        stop("url must be a single element character vector.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    if (identical(height, "maximize")) 
        height <- -1
    if (!is.null(height) && (!is.numeric(height) || (length(height) != 
        1))) 
        stop("height must be a single element numeric vector or 'maximize'.", 
            call. = FALSE)
    invisible(.Call("rs_viewer", url, height))
}
<environment: 0x7fd21312cdc8>

$warn
[1] 0

$warning.length
[1] 1000

$width
[1] 119
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay attention to the plot's y-axis label. It says: "Eigen values of original and simulated **factors and components**" (emphasis mine). *Parallel analysis (PA)* produces separate sets of eigen values for both **factors** (*factor analysis, FA*) and **components** (*principal component analysis, PCA*). While FA and PCA seem to be similar, those methods are **conceptually different**. Here's how Professor William Revelle (well-known expert in psychometric theory, maintainer of the [Personality Project](http://personality-project.org) and the author of `psych` R package) explains the difference (Revelle, 2015, p. 158):

> Although on the surface, the component model and factor model appear
>   to very similar (...), they are logically very different. In the
>   components model, components are linear sums of the variables. In the
>   factor model, on the other hand, factors are latent variables whose
>   weighted sum accounts for the common part of the observed variables.
>   In path analytic terms, for the component model, arrows go from the
>   variables to the components, while in the factor model they go from
>   the factors to the variables.

My statement above about the contents of the plot is intentionally not very accurate for pedagogical reasons (but, I hope still conceptually valid), as, in fact, `fa.parallel()` and `fa.parallel.poly()` functions plot **"the eigenvalues for a principal components solution as well as the eigen values when the communalities are estimated by a one factor *minres* solution for a given data set as well as that of n (default value = 20) randomly generated parallel data sets of the same number of variables and subjects"** (Revelle, 2015, p. 175-176) [bold emphasis mine].

**UPDATE** (based on the OP's clarification of the question):

I think that the double line output on number of factors/components is due to a second call to `fa.parallel()` or `fa.parallel.poly()` somewhere, because the standard output from `fa.parallel.poly()` contains only a **single such line**. See the MRE below.

**Code:**

```
library(psych)

data(bock)

fa.info <- fa.parallel.poly(lsat6)
summary(fa.info)
```

**Output:**

```
 See the graphic output for a description of the results
Parallel analysis suggests that the number of factors =  3  and the number of components =  1
```

[image]

**References**

Revelle, W. (2015). *An introduction to psychometric theory with applications in R.* [Website] Retrieved from http://www.personality-project.org/r/book

**NOTE:** Both my citations can be found in Chapter 6 of the referenced book, directly downloadable from http://www.personality-project.org/r/book/Chapter6.pdf.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandr Blekh, I should clarify my question -- there is two line of output, this first line suggest 4 factors and 3 components, but the second line suggest 2 factors and 2 components... I don't understand why there are 2 lines.. :(

Comment: @ceoec: Which two lines are you talking about: marked by crosses and triangles OR one of those and red-colored one?

Comment: oh I know where the confusion lies now -- the line refer to the output of the text, not in the graph.

Comment: @ceoec: Thank you for clarification. Please see the UPDATE section in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I also thought about the second call, but if that's really a second call to fa.parallel.poly, the results should be the same.... and I checked by running fa.parallel and the result did not match too, so can't explain where that line came from.

Comment: @ceoec: You're welcome. The results might very well be different, either if the function's parameters are different, or if the function is applied to a different object (for example, you may have two correlation matrices in your workspace, etc. - that's why an MRE might be helpful).

Comment: if you replace your MRE line "fa.info <- fa.parallel.poly(lsat6)" to just "fa.parallel.poly(lsat6)" (i.e. without saving that to fa.info" you will get two lines too...

Comment: @ceoec: True. However, the lines are not different, which is expected. That is not the case in your question's scenario.

Comment: The lines are different in my output! orz Let me update that in my question can't paste here...

Comment: @ceoec: I saw your update. This is quite odd. I tested my MRE on [R-Fiddle](http://r-fiddle.org). Therefore, logically, different output of the same code suggests to me that the problem is most likely with your R environment. Try to provide the full MRE or, at least, output of both `sessionInfo()` and `options()`.

Comment: Aleksandr Belkh: agree that's likely something with my R environment after looking at the output from R-Fiddle -- the eigne values line wasn't making sense in my output which may suggest some problems too... let me see if the problem still exists after I restart R...(my output of sessionInfo() and options() are crazily long now...)

Comment: This is really odd, I reboot my whole machine and start with a fresh R studio environment but I still have that strange results from your MRE :( I added sessionInfo() and options() in my questions but I do not understand them.....

Comment: Anyways huge thanks Aleksandr! With your help I know at least I can trust the first line of output... :)

Comment: @ceoec: You're very welcome! Glad to help. The fact that you've restarted your machine might not alleviate the problem, if it's something that gets loaded automatically in your `R` profiles. I looked at your session information and options - nothing really jumps at me. Hopefully, other people will lend their fresh pairs of eyes (instead of our tired ones :-) and offer some suggestions.

Comment: +1 Fantastic answer! Also great that the question didn't got (unwarrantably) closed as programming question

Comment: @user603: I greatly appreciate your kind words!

Comment: user603, hope it won't get closed. It didn't appear as programming issue at the beginning... huge thanks to @Aleksandr Blekh for trying this out on R-Fiddle or else I would never thought of that!